# Dynamical Calculator Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is a calculator which has spans from which I want to take a values(1,2,3, etc.) and two fields: First for displaying what user is typing and the second is for result of calculation.
The question how to get values so when I click on spans it will show it in the second field

Here is the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ovesyan19/vb394983/2/

```
<span>(</span>
<span>)</span>
<span class="delete">←</span>
<span class="clear">C</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
<span class="operator">÷</span>
....
```

JS:

```
var keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys span");

keys.onclick = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        alert(keys[i].innerHTML);
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you have any JS code to show?

Comment: @putvande I updated fiddle. I have some. I tried to see what it returns when I click but it returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys span");

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

`keys` is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) so you cannot attach the `onclick` on that. You need to attach it to each element in that list by doing the loop. To get the value you can then simple use `this.innerHTML`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb394983/4/)

Comment: Because by the time the `onclick` function gets triggered, `i` in `keys[i]` will be equal to `keys.length` not the current index.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a click event on the span elements if you use JQuery.
Eg:

```
$("span").click(
    function(){
        $("#calc").val($("#calc").val() + $(this).text());
    });
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/vb394983/6/

That's just to answer your question but you should really give the numbers a class such as "valueSpan" and the operators a class such as "operatorSpan" and apply the events based on these classes so that the buttons behave as you'd expect a calculator to.

Comment: Question is not tagged with jquery.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I know how to do it in jQuery. Problem is I don't know how to in native js

Comment: His display result is also in a span.. this would also use that as a click event. Should use .on like below. Also your fiddle link isn't working and I tried your code without luck on his code.

Comment: Oops copied and pasted the wrong fiddle. Fixed it. And as I said I was just answering the question, i.e how to get the value from a span when you click it. To get it behaving like a normal calculator I wouldn't use the event of any span click as I said in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.. you need to get the value of the span you are clicking and then append it into your result field. Lots more to get this calculator to work but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Fiddle Update: http://jsfiddle.net/vb394983/3/

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(".keys").on("click","span",function(){
    var clickedVal = $(this).text();
    $(".display.result").append(clickedVal);
});
```

Comment: Question is not tagged for jquery.

Comment: At least my solution works Blazemonger. Also it was fairly vague what he was asking so this was a solution that worked quickly and effectively (unlike other answer you downvoted)

Comment: I didn't downvote any of them. And the tags are clearly indicated below the question, as always.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vb394983/7/

```
   var v="",
   max_length=8,
   register=document.getElementById("register");
   // attach key events for numbers   
   var keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys span");
   for (var i = 0; l = keys.length, i < l; i++) {
       keys[i].onclick = function(){
            cal(this);
       } 
   };
   // magic display number and decimal, this formats like a cash register, modify for your own needs.
   cal = function(e){

        if (v.length === self.max_length) return;
        v += e.innerHTML;
        register.innerHTML = (parseInt(v) / 100).toFixed(2);

   }
```

Comment: I you need i can make the entire thing work like a calculator with very little code

Comment: Whilst the rest argue, my answer actually works like a real calculator: Note the arithmetic does not work, if needed i can add that two ;-)

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it by myself:)

Comment: Nice little project! enjoy I hope my example helped!

Comment: Can I have your e-mail for some questions which could be?

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery will make your life much easier:

```
$('.keys span').click(function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: I was only recommending the use of JQuery and giving an example of its benefits. Geez

Comment: Other comment by OP says: _Thanks for solution. But I know how to do it in jQuery. Problem is I don't know how to in native js_

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Didn't see that :(