# Javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm a beginner and I'm trying my first real project, making a calculator. I have a template HTML and CSS and I want to make it work by only editing the javascript. I'm stuck in the beginning and getting kinda frustrated if someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's a similar previously asked question (I think I'm supposed to include this when asking a question): [Dynamical Calculator Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268118/dynamical-calculator-javascript)

Here's my script so far: https://jsfiddle.net/andthatch/an73my86/#&togetherjs=4goj5AV6Qk

Working now :) thanks guys. I'll stop back if I get stuck again.

```
var divElement = document.getElementById("calculator");
var keys = divElement.getElementsByTagName("span");
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');
var decimalAdded = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        var inputVal = input[0].innerHTML;
        var buttonVal = this.innerHTML;

        if(buttonVal === 'C') {
            input[0].innerHTML = '';
            decimalAdded = false;
        }
        else{
           input[0].innerHTML+=buttonVal;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an html collection and you treat it as a single element. Developer Tools are your friend.

Comment: I'd guess that the issue is that you're getting a list for `input` but expecting a single element.

Comment: Link to a fiddle for everyone to have an easier time looking into it:

https://jsfiddle.net/efc3hbt8/

Comment: As far as I can see here, you never put the values in `screen` div, and of course the `intput` variable is an HTTPCollection, so you have to keep the first element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your script file.input is a collection of elements as it is obtained through `getElementsByClassName`.So you have to specify the index for the only element under class 'screen' as its returning an array .Also use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)  instead of using 'onClick' as property on object

```
var divElement = document.getElementById("calculator");
var keys = divElement.getElementsByTagName("span");
var input = divElement.getElementsByClassName("screen");
var decimalAdded = false;

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        var inputVal = input[0].innerHTML;
        var buttonVal = this.innerHTML;

        if(buttonVal === 'C') {
            input[0].innerHTML = '';
            decimalAdded = false;
        }else{
           input[0].innerHTML+=buttonVal;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying to run that now and still not having luck. Here's what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/efc3hbt8/6/

Comment: i ckecked your jsfiddel.in your fiddle you wrote var screenElement=divElement.getElementsByClassName.should be var input = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');